# How do I pass a parameter from an array used to populate a drop drown list via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

I have the following view:

```
index.html.js
<h5>Select your state:</h5>
<%= select_tag "state", options_for_select(@states.collect{|x| x[0]}), :onchange => '$.get("/home/populate_options")' %>
```

Where @states is an array of state abbreviations like:

```
@states
  [
    ['AK', 'AK'],
    ['AL', 'AL'],
    . . .
  ]
```

How do I pass a parameter containing the selected state value (if Alaska is selected, "AK" should be sent to the controller action) to my controller action via ajax?

Do I have to manually build up the url within my javascript before sending `$.get("/home/populate_options")` so that it looks more like `$.get("/home/populate_options/AK")`?  Maybe I need to change the way I use the helper so I can actually use 'rails-like' helpers and just send the parameter using a symbol :state => "AK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

When you have `@states = [['AK','AK'],['AL','AL']]` like this. You don't need to use `collect` just `@states` is enough.

And for sending values in params `onchange` you can do like below:

```
  <%= select_tag "state", options_for_select(@states), :onchange => '$.get("/home/populate_options?state="+$(this).val())' %>
```

But in your question it is not clear that where exactly you are populating data from `ajax`.

Comment: Perfect!  I had not refactored up to that point and the `collect` stuff was definitely unnecessary.  Thank you, the `?state="+$(this).val()` was exactly what I needed.